# What features does an android device returing true to PROPERTY_SUPPORT_MIC_NEAR_ULTRASOUND and PROPERTY_SUPPORT_SPEAKER_NEAR_ULTRASOUND have

Tags: android, audio, microphone, frequency-analysis, speaker

I was checking the Android API documentation and inside the AudioManager page I found the following properties.

```
PROPERTY_SUPPORT_MIC_NEAR_ULTRASOUND (Added in API level 23)

String PROPERTY_SUPPORT_MIC_NEAR_ULTRASOUND

Used as a key for getProperty(String) to determine if the default microphone audio source supports near-ultrasound frequencies (range of 18 - 21 kHz).


PROPERTY_SUPPORT_SPEAKER_NEAR_ULTRASOUND (Added in API level 23)

String PROPERTY_SUPPORT_SPEAKER_NEAR_ULTRASOUND

Used as a key for getProperty(String) to determine if the default speaker audio path supports near-ultrasound frequencies (range of 18 - 21 kHz).
```

I was wondering what is the technical meaning of "supports near-ultrasound frequencies"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it inside Android 7.0 Compatibility Definition Doc

7.8.3. Near-Ultrasound

Near-Ultrasound audio is the 18.5 kHz to 20 kHz band. Device implementations MUST correctly report the support of near-ultrasound audio capability via the AudioManager.getProperty API as follows:

```
If PROPERTY_SUPPORT_MIC_NEAR_ULTRASOUND is "true", then the following requirements must be met by the VOICE_RECOGNITION and UNPROCESSED audio sources:
    The microphone's mean power response in the 18.5 kHz to 20 kHz band MUST be no more than 15 dB below the response at 2 kHz.
    The microphone's unweighted signal to noise ratio over 18.5 kHz to 20 kHz for a 19 kHz tone at -26 dBFS MUST be no lower than 50 dB.
If PROPERTY_SUPPORT_SPEAKER_NEAR_ULTRASOUND is "true", then the speaker's mean response in 18.5 kHz - 20 kHz MUST be no lower than 40 dB below the response at 2 kHz.
```

Comment: What's the use of it though? And what about making such sounds via the speakers?

Comment: If you want to implement an app that uses ultrasound to work you had to make your own tools to evaluate the actual performance of the device. With this you can know if the actual device will work by just querying the API (I still use my own tools because I don't trust in this blindly but it is still useful)

Comment: But what for example ? What do you do with near-ultrasound? The only place I hear ultra-sound is used, is for checking that the fetus is ok in a pregnant woman.

Comment: Jajaja I could say you so much that I created https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/173723/near-ultrasound-frequency-apps-for-mobile-or-any-other-devices?tab=general let me know when you are there

Comment: I don't see anything special on this link

Comment: It is a chat room to debate about this and not overload the comment section

Comment: Just to give you a start: 
There are many applications in which this technology can be used. In general any application in which a short distance between devices and low transfer speed could solve a problem. By building a sound modulation protocol that allows transmitting digital information encoded in audio waves it is possible to perform tasks such as authentication, contact, access or payment info exchange, customer loyalty programs follow up, device indoor positioning, etc.

Comment: This is a bit weird application to the tech, seeing that we already have other ways to do it. What could be the speed of download/upload of such a communication, and what's the range?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173771/discussion-between-vmmf-and-android-developer).

Answer (score 0):

Supports near-ultrasound frequencies means the microphone can record sound in the range of 18 - 21 kHz (as quoted from the documentation you cited.)

Comment: What is the use of such hardware feature ? They even have one for the speakers (to make a near-ultrasound sound) ...